# Access Firebase frontend with info from GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have inherited a Swift iOS project with that includes Firebase, and I need to troubleshoot a first login with account creation issue, so I expect it will involve repeatedly removing a single account.

Is it possible to access the databases web frontend of the database from the information included in the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file that was included in the project? Or might I need some information from the previous developer.

The `DATABASE_URL` ends in firebaseio.com.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  GoogleService-Info.plist is just a configuration file that was downloaded from the console, to be used when building the app.  That's its only purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the url from `DATABASE_URL` into a web browser will expand the URL to something like `console.firebase.google/com/u/<number>/project/<root>` where:

- `<number>` will be 0, 1, 2, etc. But probably 0.
- `<root>` will be
  the project name, which is also the first part of the DATABASE_URL
  string in GoogleService-Info.plist

You might find that the URL returns a page that states "There was an error while processing the request. Try Again". This is because you're logged in on a different Google account that cannot access that DB. Logging in with the right account should get you the page you want. (This will also change `<number>` to a new value which is the one you'll always want to use when accessing this DB)

After that you can navigate to `authentication/users` to see your created accounts, and you can sort by creation date to easily access the accounts you want to delete.